# Erro retorna Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of null ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, html, string, substring

Fui tentar montar um *script* que verificasse o estado no qual foi emitido o CPF. Porém não estou conseguindo utilizar o `substring`, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of null

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
  function verificar(){

    var cpf = document.getElementById(cpf);

  if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "0"){

alert("Rio Grande do Sul");

}

else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "1"){

alert(" Distrito Federal – Goiás – Mato Grosso – Mato Grosso do Sul – Tocantins ");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "2"){

alert("  Pará – Amazonas – Acre – Amapá – Rondônia – Roraima");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "3"){

alert(" Ceará – Maranhão – Piauí");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "4"){

alert(" Pernambuco – Rio Grande do Norte – Paraíba – Alagoas ");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "5"){

alert(" Bahia – Sergipe   ");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "6"){

alert("Minas Gerais ");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "7"){

alert("Rio de Janeiro – Espírito Santo");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "8"){

alert("São Paulo");

}
else if(cpf.substring(7,9) == "9"){

alert("Paraná – Santa Catarina");
}
}
  </script>
  <title>CPF</title>
</head>

<body>
 <p>Informar CPF</p><input type="text" id="cpf">
 <input type="button" id="opcao" name="opcao" value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você está querendo pegar um campo do HTML então tem que usar seu nome, no caso quer o campo `"cpf"` e não a variável `cpf` como nome do campo, faltou as aspas ali. Não sei o quanto é só um erro de digitação ou falta de entendimento do que é uma variável, um literal *string*, etc. Além disso precisa pegar a propriedade `value` do elemento para pegar o valor e não o elemento todo.

E precisa pegar um caractere e não 2 como está pegando.

```js
function verificar() {
    var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value.substring(7, 8);
    if (cpf == "0") alert("Rio Grande do Sul");
    else if (cpf == "1") alert(" Distrito Federal – Goiás – Mato Grosso – Mato Grosso do Sul – Tocantins ");
    else if (cpf == "2") alert("  Pará – Amazonas – Acre – Amapá – Rondônia – Roraima");
    else if (cpf == "3") alert(" Ceará – Maranhão – Piauí");
    else if (cpf == "4") alert(" Pernambuco – Rio Grande do Norte – Paraíba – Alagoas ");
    else if (cpf == "5") alert(" Bahia – Sergipe   ");
    else if (cpf == "6") alert("Minas Gerais ");
    else if (cpf == "7") alert("Rio de Janeiro – Espírito Santo");
    else if (cpf == "8") alert("São Paulo");
    else if (cpf == "9") alert("Paraná – Santa Catarina");
}
```

```html
<p>Informar CPF</p><input type = "text" id = "cpf">
 <input type = "button" id = "opcao" name = "opcao" value = "Verificar" onclick = "verificar()"><br>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/SubString.js).

Dá para simplificar mais, mas não vou fazê-lo para não introduzir um conceito novo.